# How to set different admin ports for different Zookeeper Docker containers?

Tags: java, docker, apache-zookeeper

I am creating a cluster of three zookeeper docker containers on a Single system.
Admin server of the first zookeeper docker is up using port 8080, so for other two Zoo containers, it is giving "Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:8080, address in use". I am using zoo version as "zookeeper:3.5.6".

Now my question is how to assign different admin port to the zookeeper admin server other than 8080?

I have tried different options to set the admin server on different ports, but nothing worked.

```
1) - zookeeper.admin.serverPort=8078
2) - ZOO_CFG_EXTRA="admin.serverPort=8077"
3) - admin.serverPort=8078
```

Below is the docker compose for one zookeeper.

```
 zk2:
  hostname: ${LOCAL_HOST}
  image: ${ZOOKEEPER_IMAGE}
  environment:
    - u=${USER}:${USER}
    - JVM_OPTS=-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
    - ZOO_MY_ID=${ZOO_MY_ID2}
    - ZOO_SERVERS=${ZOO_SERVER_1} ${ZOO_SERVER_2} ${ZOO_SERVER_3}
    - ZOO_ADMINSERVER_ENABLED=true
    - ZOO_STANDALONE_ENABLED=false
    - zookeeper.admin.serverPort=8078
  volumes:
    - ${VOLUMES_PATH}/zk2/data:/data
    - ${VOLUMES_PATH}/zk2/logs:/datalog
  network_mode: "host"
  ports:
    - ${ZOOK_CL_PORT2}:${ZOOK_CL_PORT2}
    - ${ZOOK_SR_PORT2}:${ZOOK_SR_PORT2}
    - ${ZOOK_EL_PORT2}:${ZOOK_EL_PORT2}
    - ${ZOOK_ADM_PORT2}:8078"
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: In the docker compose, you can specify the zookeeper 3 times, every time with a different port. Also, make the 1st one as a master node, the other two as workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the docker compose file you posted, the problematic element is the
  `network_mode: "host"`. Citing the official documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

So, in fact, every one of the three zookeeper quorum members that you fire up is competing on allocating the 8080 port, ignoring the port binding you defined later on.

Comment: thanks @Arvanitis, I missed to remove network_mode from docker-compose zookeeper definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Admin server port 8080 is available only inside the container until you expose it with port mappings. If you want to expose the port to docker host you should assign different port mappings to both of your zookeeper container.

In this case, you are trying to change the container's internal admin server port which is not required. You can take the example of following docker-compose file -

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: 'zookeeper'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      ZOO_SERVER_ID: 1
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
      ZOO_ADMINSERVER_ENABLED: "true"
      ZOO_SERVERS: "zoo1:2888:3888,zoo2:2888:3888"
  zoo2:
    image: 'zookeeper'
    ports:
      - '3181:2181'
      - '8078:8080'
    environment:
      ZOO_SERVER_ID: 2
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
      ZOO_ADMINSERVER_ENABLED: "true"
      ZOO_SERVERS: "zoo1:2888:3888,zoo2:2888:3888"
```

**zoo1** - Port 8080 is available inside the container and we are exposing the same port to the docker host.
**zoo2** - Port 8080 is available inside the container but we are exposing different port(8078) to the docker host.

Now you can access the interface using port `8080` for first container and `8078` for the second container from your docker host.

Comment: hi @Ravi thanks for reply, but I have already tried the same (internal container port 80 to different exposed port 81) but inside the container also it does not let me use the same port 8080 as it is already used by another zookeeper container, with exception "org.apache.zookeeper.server.admin.AdminServer$AdminServerException: Problem starting AdminServer on address 0.0.0.0, port 8080 and command URL /commands
"

Comment: hi @SuvenduGhosh, Can you please share your full `docker-compose.yml` file if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this

```
ZOO_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER:9999
```

> ZOO_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER: Admin server port. Default: 8080

[bitnami/zookeeper Reference URL](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/zookeeper/)